# rewrite joomla pagination sef url with htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I want to rewrite my link from

http://my-domain.com/category/article?page=2

to

http://my-domain.com/category/article/page-2

i try this rule in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^article/page-([0-9]+)$ article?page=$1 [R=301,L]
```

with Rewrite Engine On and remove # before RewriteBase

But it doesnt work

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([0-9]*)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/category/article/page-%1 [R=302,L]
```